# Is there any way to make my google maps the same when i print my website

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a page with a maps and KML + some markers, and when i print (CTRL+P) my page, i only see the top left corner of my map and the default zoom is not the good one. And seriously, i haven't found a single solution on the web, any tips ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The javascript-based Google Map is using background images for tiles and background images are not printable.

You can include an alternative static map for printing:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1#quick_example

Make it visible for printing by css whereas the javascript-based map would only be visible on screen:

```
@media screen {
  #static_map {
    display: none;
  }
  #js_map {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media print {
  #js_map {
    display: none;
  }
  #static_map {
    display: block;
  }
}
```